# clone a table row

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Hi I have two rows 
like :

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <%:Html.Label("Name")%>
    <%:Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Name)%>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <%:Html.Label("Age")%>
    <%:Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Age)%>
  </td>
</tr>
```

How should I clone these two rows and add it after the completion of last row.
I tried something like this:

```
$("#" + tableId + "tbody")
  .clone(true)
  .insertAfter("#" + tableId + " tr:last");
$('#' + tableId + ' tbody:first>tr:last>td:last')
  .empty()
  .append("<input type=\"image\" id=\"imgDelete\" name=\"delete\" alt='' class=\"delete\" onclick='DeleteTableRow(this)' />");
```

Comment: Wow please edit this to make it somewhat readable...

Comment: Do you want to add the row at server side or client side? what you reying to do is in client side using jquery. If server side you can use asp.net mvc helper.

Answer (score 0):

I you only want to clone the 2 rows, you could give them and id, for instance:

```
<tr id="toClone_0">
  <td>
    <%:Html.Label("Name")%>
    <%:Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Name)%>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr id="toClone_1">
  <td>
    <%:Html.Label("Age")%>
    <%:Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Age)%>
  </td>
</tr>
```

then in jQuery:

```
// select the elements whose id starts with 'toClone_'
// false to avoid cloning of event handlers, true ohterwise
var clonedRows = $("id^='toClone_'").clone(false);

// insert the cloned rows after the last row
$("#" + tableId + "tr:last").after(clonedRows);
```